# Custom plugin settings add on admin nav bar

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I want to control my plugin on the admin navbar but I can't found a way for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate Craft CMS plugin and module code scaffolding on https://pluginfactory.io/ please turn on switch for CP section and then your plugin path/src/.php file in change $hasCpSection true.

Once you do the above changes your plugin will display on the nav bar.  I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [EVENT_REGISTER_CP_NAV_ITEMS](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/cp-section.html) event in the main plugin class. From the docs:

```
use craft\events\RegisterCpNavItemsEvent;
use craft\web\twig\variables\Cp;
use yii\base\Event;

public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    Event::on(
        Cp::class,
        Cp::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_NAV_ITEMS,
        function(RegisterCpNavItemsEvent $event) {
            $event->navItems[] = [
                'url' => 'section-url',
                'label' => 'Section Label',
                'icon' => '@mynamespace/path/to/icon.svg',
            ];
        }
    );

    // ...
}
```